# Android Start Activity from another class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, nullpointerexception

Hi guys I am new in android and I am trying  to create a bottom menu which appear in all activities. So I created the menu in xml layout and attached it to the layout of my application using

```
 <include android:layout_width="fill_parent" layout="@layout/menu"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Now i want to link  this layout to a class which will contain starting activities and change the color of the active menu ...

The problem is when I open an activity using Intent in other class `(menu.class)` I got `NullPointerException`

I have added the activities in AndroidManifest. I'm able to start the new activity in main class (MainActivity.class) but when i try to do it in menu class I get NullPointerException.

this is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        menu m = new menu((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mn1),(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mn2),
                (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mn3),(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mn4));
        m.btmmenu(new Intent(this, time.class));
    } }
```

the menu class :

```
public class menu extends Activity {
    LinearLayout mn1,mn2,mn3,mn4;
    public menu(LinearLayout mn1,LinearLayout mn2,LinearLayout mn3,LinearLayout mn4) {
        this.mn1=mn1;
        this.mn2=mn2;
        this.mn3=mn3;
        this.mn4=mn4;
    }
    public void btmmenu(final Intent i) {
        mn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    } }
```

i tried to send the Intent in the constructor i also tried to create the intent in the menu class but i always get NullPointerException

```
02-02 14:12:21.511    3319-3319/com.android.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3429)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3600)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3568)
            at com.xochn.okanime.menu$1.onClick(menu.java:21)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

anyone know how to do this ?

thanks.

Comment: Where are you defining ´time´?

Comment: `public class menu extends Activity` + `new menu(...)` ??? ... please read about Activity lifecycle ... never use operator new on class that extends Activity ... asked so many times ... you need to pass context somehow to start activity from non Activity class ...

Comment: @barq time is the class i want to open and could do that in MainActivity without any problems

Comment: @selvin sorry like i said i am new in android i am gonna try to find another way to do that but i have this problem in line startActivity(i) it mean i could print Log.d("msj","msj") or i could do anything and i still don't get NullPointerException it only happen when i start new activity

Comment: Being new is not an excuse, please at least know the basics by reading documentation. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: thanks @M-WaJeEh i know being new is not an excuse but we learn from our mistakes ;) anyway problem solved thanks everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't extend an `Activity` and try to create it with `new`. this just doesn't work like that.
You need to have a `Context` so you can call the `startActivity` method.

I suggest you do the following changes:

1. Extend `View` or a sub-class of it instead of extending an `Activity`. This will make you use a context as a parameter in its constructor and call its `super(context)`
2. Use `getContext().startActivity()` instead of `startActivity` with the Intent to start the child `Activity`

Comment: thanks i remove extends Activity and i solve the problem by using context

Answer (score 1):

Calling the startActivity method requires a context, which you're not including when you do the call.

Try extending a view to your activity and use this:

```
Intent launchNewIntent = new Intent(CurrentClass.this,SecondClass.class);
startActivityForResult(launchNewIntent, 0);
```